# Vue3 how import Jquery AMD plugin?

Tags: jquery, vuejs3

I'm currently migrating my site to Vue and would like some help.

I transfer only the layout and set up data exchange, the visual of the site remains the same. That is, I connect an external bundle to Vue, which is implemented in jquery.

I don’t connect it, but in a sense I use it, I use the source code of the old bundle in my components.

It seems that everything went well with jquery and other plugins working, but problems arose with slick-carousel and its AMD variation.

I can’t do an import, the error still occurs (...).find(...).slick is not a function.

In the config I use a simple provide.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      })
```

Other modules, bootstrap for example tooltipster, work without problems.

I tried changing the source code of the slick-carousel module, building the application with the parser { amd: false } parameter
So far no success.

How to connect? I don’t want to rewrite some UI carousel for Vue.